# Single colorbar for two subplots changes the size of one of the subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to add a single `colorbar` for two `matshow`s using mainly the code at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7875688/how-can-i-create-a-standard-colorbar-for-a-series-of-plots-in-python) and [here](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/users/overview.html#colorbar-whose-height-or-width-in-sync-with-the-master-axes).

My code is the following now, but the problem is that the colorbar moderates the size of the plot on the right. How can I prevent that?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
# Generate some data that where each slice has a different range
# (The overall range is from 0 to 2)
data = np.random.random((2,10,10))
data *= np.array([1.5, 2.0])[:,None,None]

# Plot each slice as an independent subplot
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2)
for dat, ax in zip(data, axes.flat):
    # The vmin and vmax arguments specify the color limits
    im = ax.imshow(dat, vmin=0, vmax=2)

# Make an axis for the colorbar on the right side
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)
fig.colorbar(im, cax=cax)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Just a later reference for myself. This might help:
http://matplotlib.org/1.4.3/examples/axes_grid/demo_axes_grid2.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matplotlib 2 Subplots, 1 Colorbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784201/matplotlib-2-subplots-1-colorbar)

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple approaches in the answers to [Matplotlib 2 Subplots, 1 Colorbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784201/matplotlib-2-subplots-1-colorbar?rq=1). The last is simplest but doesn't work for me (the imshow plots are the same size, but *both* shorter than the colorbar). You could also run the colorbar under the images:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
data = np.random.random((2,10,10))
data *= np.array([1.5, 2.0])[:,None,None]

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2)
for dat, ax in zip(data, axes.flat):
     im = ax.imshow(dat, vmin=0, vmax=2)

fig.colorbar(im,  ax=axes.ravel().tolist(), orientation='horizontal')
plt.show()
```

[image]