# Why has subplot of matplotlib not the same size?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-plot

I am building a classifier in Python and would like to evaluate it.
I already built some code that is plotting a few different metrics per class. Plot_metric() is a self defined function.

```
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 5, width_ratios=[5, 1, 1, 1, 1])
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0])
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[1])
ax3 = plt.subplot(gs[2])
ax4 = plt.subplot(gs[3])
ax5 = plt.subplot(gs[4])

skplot.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix(confusion_y_test, confusion_y_pred, ax=ax1, labels=[0,1,2,3,4])
plot_metric(accuracy_per_class_array, "Class accuracy", ax2, cmap=plt.cm.Blues)
plot_metric(precision_per_class_array, "Class precision", ax3, cmap=plt.cm.Blues)
plot_metric(recall_per_class_array, "Class recall", ax4, cmap=plt.cm.Blues)
plot_metric(f1_per_class_Array, "Class F1", ax5, cmap=plt.cm.Blues)
```

I use every axis to plot a different metric and the confusion matrix as you can see in the picture.

But **why is the last column smaller than the others?** I would like it to be the same height as the other plots.

[image]

Update:

The code of the plot_metric():

```
def plot_metric(metric_array, metric_name, axis, display_labels=None, cmap="viridis"):
"""
plotted_cm : instance of `ConfusionMatrixDisplay`
    Result of `sklearn.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix`
axis : matplotlib `AxesSubplot`
    Result of `fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)`
display_labels : list of labels or None
    Human-readable class names
cmap : colormap, optional
    Optional colormap
"""

n_classes = len(metric_array)

if display_labels is None:
    labels = np.arange(n_classes)
else:
    labels = display_labels

axis.imshow(
    np.array(metric_array).reshape(n_classes, 1),
    interpolation="nearest",
    cmap=cmap,
)

for i, value in enumerate(metric_array):
    axis.text(0, i, format(value, ".2g"), ha="center", va="center")


axis.set(
    yticks=np.arange(len(metric_array)),
    xlabel=metric_name,
    yticklabels=labels,
)
axis.tick_params(
    axis="x", bottom=False, labelbottom=False,
)
axis.set_ylim((len(metric_array) - 0.5, -0.5))
```

Comment: I think the colormap legend (but not its labels) is included in the width of the last column, but I'm not sure why that would be the case. Can you share your `plot_metric` code?

Comment: The recommended approach is to place the colorbar in a separate subplot. See also [this tutorial example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/colorbar_placement.html) or [Single colorbar for two subplots changes the size of one of the subplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29447352/single-colorbar-for-two-subplots-changes-the-size-of-one-of-the-subplots)