# How display one white pixel with mathplot imshow

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to display one white pixel with mathplot:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow([[0.99]], cmap='gray', interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
```

but it shows black. Why?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you only give `imshow` one value, so the colour scale is set around that value and it gets painted as the minimum value of the scale (thus black).

Specify `vmin` and `vmax`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7879159/3026320):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow([[0.99]], cmap='gray', interpolation='nearest', vmin=0, vmax=1)
plt.show()
```

More importantly, you need `vmax`, which will be mapped to white, to be the value you give `imshow`, and `vmin` to be smaller than that:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

max_value = np.random.random()
min_value = -max_value # for instance

plt.imshow([[max_value]], cmap='gray', interpolation='nearest',
           vmin=min_value, vmax=max_value)
plt.show()
```