# Iterating over imshow and plotting multiple 2D maps with common colorbar using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour, imshow

I have 4 input data files. I am trying to plot 2D-contour maps using by reading data from these input files with a **common** colorbar. I have taken inspiration from the following answers :

1) [How can I create a standard colorbar for a series of plots in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7875688/how-can-i-create-a-standard-colorbar-for-a-series-of-plots-in-python)

2)[Matplotlib 2 Subplots, 1 Colorbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784201/matplotlib-2-subplots-1-colorbar)

Code :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Reading data from input files 
dat1 = np.genfromtxt('curmapdown.dat', delimiter='  ')
dat2 = np.genfromtxt('curmapup.dat', delimiter='  ')
dat3 = np.genfromtxt('../../../zika/zika1/CalculateCurvature/curmapdown.dat', delimiter='  ')
dat4 = np.genfromtxt('../../../zika/zika1/CalculateCurvature/curmapup.dat', delimiter='  ')

data=[]
for i in range(1,5):
    data.append('dat%d'%i)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
# Error comes from this part
for ax,dat in zip(axes.flat,data):
     im = ax.imshow(dat, vmin=0, vmax=1)

fig.colorbar(im, ax=axes.ravel().tolist())
plt.show()
```

Error :

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "2dmap.py", line 15, in <module>
 im = ax.imshow(dat, vmin=0, vmax=1)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1814, in inner
 return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 4947, in imshow
 im.set_data(X)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 449, in set_data
raise TypeError("Image data can not convert to float")
```

TypeError: Image data can not convert to float

Comment: So, what is the problem? Also, it helps if you have a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention. I have edited the question and included the error.

Comment: Can you show an example of what is in the dat files?

Comment: Only problem is how do put elements of `data` in the imshow. Examples are given in the questions I have taken inspiration from. They have used random matrices  which work fine but I am unsure how to iterate over matrices  which I have got from input files.

Comment: Sure. Here it is. https://pastebin.com/2qFgPVaq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are appending the *string* `"dat1"` into a list called `data`. When plotting this you are trying to convert this string to float, which obviously fails

```
plt.imshow("hello")
```

will recreate the error you are seeing.

You want the data itself which you have loaded into variables called `dat1` etc. So you would want to remove the first for loop and do something like

```
data = [dat1, dat2, dat3, dat4]
```